# If a quadratic equation in $x\in R$ is $\lt 0$ then is $D\lt 0$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

The answer to the question "Find the range of values of ${a}$ satisfying $-3\lt \frac{x^2+ax-2}{x^2-x+1}\lt 2$" given in the book is

> Since $x^{2}-x+1>0$ for all real $x$, the given set of inequalities may be expressed as $-3\left(x^{2}-x+1\right)<x^{2}+$ $a x-2<2\left(x^{2}-x+1\right)$
>
> On simplification, we obtain
> \begin{array}{lll}
> 4 x^{2}+(a-3) x+1>0 & \text { and } & x^{2}-(a+2) x+4>0 \text { for which } \\
> (a-3)^{2}-16<0 & \text { and } & (a+2)^{2}-16<0
> \end{array}
> or $\quad-4<\mathrm{a}-3<4 \quad$ and $\quad-4<\mathrm{a}+2<4$
>
> $\therefore \quad$ a lies between $-1$ and 7 as well as between $-6$ and $2$.
> [image]
>
> The range of values for a is $(-1,2)$.

I have a problem with the fifth line from the start of the block i.e. how can one get from $4 x^{2}+(a-3) x+1>0$ (say it equation $1$) to $(a-3)^{2}-16<0 $, assuming $x\in R?$

[Note that $(a-3)^{2}-16$ is discriminant of equation 1].

If I did the same for the quadratic $x^2-4x-77<0$ ($x\in R$) then I get $16+308<0$ which is absurd. Is the book wrong? If not why is right in that step? If wrong how will we solve the question?

Thank you, for reading my question.

Comment: In order for $f(x)=4x^2 + (a-3)x +1 > 0$ for all $x,$ the discriminant of $f(x)$ must be negative, otherwise $f(x)$ would intercept with the $x$-axis, contradiction $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson But it isn't $\forall x\in R$ it is $x\in R$. Both are not interchangeable.

Comment: No, the intended question (I believe) is, "find all the values of ${a}$ such that $-3\lt \frac{x^2+ax-2}{x^2-x+1}\lt 2$ is true for all $x.$" This is one of the many cases where the author could have been clearer by being more explicit. This is all too common among maths authors unfortunately...

Comment: Do you see how this also answers your $x^2 - 4x - 77 < 0$ question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes. Because this equation is not true for all x in R.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Indeed it happens many times that an author doesn't include the critical information, which causes a lot of time wastage and stress to me. How do you deal with this?

Comment: that's a good question. Personally, I have thought about writing to the authors all their mistakes for a fee, but I don't know how that would work. So I just sift through all the material myself and find the errors as I go along. If you suspect an author has made a mistake in a maths book, there's a good chance someone would have asked it on here (math.stackexchange), or some other maths site. If not, you can ask it as a question on here. Also, the question you *just asked*:

Comment: " Indeed it happens many times that an author doesn't include the critical information, which causes a lot of time wastage and stress to me. How do you deal with this?" seems like a good question - why not ask that as a question on this site? But one possible answer to this question is that $1)$ all authors make errors because they are human, so you should just accept that. $2)$ you get better at spotting what the question *intended* to be the more maths you read, so you waste less time. Like for the original question, I was able to spot the mistake from the author whereas you weren't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as you quote it seems a little ill-posed to me. It should say something like: "Find all values $a$ such that $-3< \frac{x^{2}+ax-2}{x^{2}-x+1}<2$ **for all real** $x$."

If for a given $a$ the quadratic equation $4x^{2}+(a-3)x+1$ is strictly positive for all real $x$, then it cannot have any real roots. The only way a quadratic equation can have no real roots is precisely when the discriminant is negative.

In $x^{2}-4x-77$ there is no parameter $a$ to be chosen, so we cannot find any condition on $a$.

Comment: The question in the book is the same as I have written, and I am happy to see that I had taught the same what you wrote! I was also thinking that the question is incomplete and should have included $\forall x\in R.$